# Back4app Parse-sever : Find just get just the id not all data

Tags: vue.js, parse-server, back4app

Im on a find situacion because the result of the Parse.query is just the id and I had other columns :(

Response of find:

```
 [{"_objCount":0,"className":"DivorceCase","id":"8Ab15ASBX3"}]
```

Actual Code:

```
// Your corresponding keys
    Parse.initialize("xxx", "xxx");
// For back4app applications
    Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com'

var app = new Vue({
        el: "#AttorneyCases",
        data: {             
    DivorceCase :{},      
        },
  mounted:function(){
    new Parse.Query("DivorceCase").descending("createdAt").find()
    .then((DivorceCaseResponse) => {
      this.DivorceCase = DivorceCaseResponse;
    })
  }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, nataliec!

The final code is:

```
mounted: function() {
    var Case = Parse.Object.extend("DivorceCase");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Case);
    query.find()
        .then((Ids) => {

                Ids.forEach(element => {

                    var Case = Parse.Object.extend("DivorceCase");
                    var query = new Parse.Query(Case);
                    query.get(element.id)
                        .then((DivorceCaseResponse) => {
                                // The object was retrieved successfully.
                                this.DivorceCases.push(DivorceCaseResponse.get("BasicInfo"));
                            },
                            (e) => {
                                // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                                swal({
                                    position: 'center',
                                    type: 'error',
                                    title: e.message,
                                    customClass: 'swal-wide'
                                })
                            });

                });



            },
            (e) => {
                // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                swal({
                    position: 'center',
                    type: 'error',
                    title: e.message,
                    customClass: 'swal-wide'
                })

            });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to get the value of the other columns field, you need to use the code below:

```
var columnName = DivorceCaseResponse.get("columnName");
```

You can check more about retrieving objects [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#retrieving-objects).